# Disk space issues

Tags: 11.10

The following is the output that I get for `df -h`. I am using dual booting with windows and ubuntu.Could I think of re allocating space for drives in order to  make the operations easier.Or can I go along with the same partition for the time being?

```
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6  8.9G 6.8G 1.7G  81%  /
udev       620M 4.0K 620M  1%   /dev
tmpfs      251M 756K 250M  1%   /run
none       5.0M 0    5.0M  0%   /run/lock
none       627M 320K 627M  1%   /run/shm
cgroup     627M 0    627M  0%   /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sr0   491M 491M 0     100% /media/VCD
```

Regards

Abdul

Answer (score 1):

Ok as you have not specified what kind of dual boot you have implemented (whether you have installed inside windows or not) If you have installed outside windows as a separate OS you can use tune2fs,ntfsresize,resize2fs as per your convenience